# Search string according to specific format

Tags: c#, string

I'm having problem searching text with certain format. my file looks as below.

```
britney     ak4564gc1    18
scott       ak3333hc2    28
jenny       ad4564gc3    32
amy         ak4564gc4    29
```

I would like to search for worknumber with certain format which is dynamic. here is my code. the format must have specific length with * as change variable.

```
for (int line = 0; line <= Countline(OriFile)-1; line++)
{
    var desiredText = File.ReadAllLines(OriFile).ElementAt(line);
    string s = desiredText.ToString();
    string b = s.Substring(WONUmStart, WONumLength);
    //format changeable(I changed it to make it easier to understand)
    if(b.Contains(a.TextBox.ToString())) //textbox value "ak****gc*"
    {
        if (WoNum != b)
        {
            WoNum = b;
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(reportfile, true);
            sw.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(OriFile) + 
                         " " + 
                         WoNum + 
                         "   " + 
                         Path.GetFileName(MergeFile));
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody guide me?

Comment: What is `*`, an arbitrary char with arbitrary length?

Comment: Try Regex Class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, that is correct tim

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *regular expressions* with *Linq*, e.g.

```
string pattern = @"\bak.{3}gc.{1}\b";

var result = File
  .ReadLines(OriFile)
  .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern)) // if we expect at most one match per line 
  .Where(match => match.Success)
  .Select(match => match.Value);  

 ...

File.WriteAllLines(reportfile, result.
  Select(line => string.Format("{0} {1}   {2}", 
    Path.GetFileName(OriFile), line, Path.GetFileName(MergeFile))));
```

Comment: the value "ak***gc*" need to be able to be able to change at random through textbox actually. i directly insert an example format for mutual understanding. using regex, i'm need to fix the format.